# Why const QString& param return bad const char* pointer to data

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, pointers

Find out interesting bug: when I pass `const QString&` parameter and then get `const char*` pointer to data that stored within `const QString&`, pointer points to bad data (some characters that not seemed as I send to function).

```
LogbookNote LBHasher::makePropsFromPseudoElement(const QString& id)
{
   LogbookNote rv;
   if (m_ctx->currentTrim) {
    const char* charId = id.toLatin1().data();
    ...
    qDebug() << charId;
}
```

And calling code:

```
LogbookNote LBHasher::makePropsByNameConvention(QString id)
{
   LogbookNote g;
   if (id.startsWith("_ctx_")) {
       g = makePropsFromPseudoElement(id);
 ...
 }
```

As you can mention, to calling method id comes as `QString`, i.e. whole copy of `QString` object. And thus `const QString&` can be a strong (not broken, to deleted temporary object, for example) reference.

Why such behavior occurred?

Comment: Btw... ```qDebug() << qPrintable( id )```

Comment: Maybe the title for this question has to be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id.toLatin1()` creates a temporary `QByteArray` instance. You then store a pointer to the buffer managed by that temporary. At the semicolon, the temporary is destroyed, leaving your pointer dangling; using that pointer later exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: OK, it's point. But why such a behaviour occurred just once ? Mean when I call this code second time , pointer works well.

Comment: "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

[`QString::toLatin1`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) returns a `QByteArray` by value which means it is a temporary object.  That `QByteArray` is destroyed at then end of that line(full expression) leaving you with a pointer to invalid object and using it is undefined behavior.